# Bash - find regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I need to find some text using a regular expression and color it. The regular expression is a parameter of my script.

So I am able to do this for this parameter:

```
./color_skript.sh 'hello'
```

program:

```
word=$1
var=$(echo -e $line | grep $word  | sed -e "s/${word}/${color}${word}${endColor}/g")
```

It works and it finds "hello" in every line. However when I have this parameter:

```
./color_skript.sh 'hel[a-z]*\>'
```

It should find every word which starts "hel" and ends with any letters. For example: "helaa", "helab","helzz" ... etc.

How I can do this?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Comment: What does it currently do when you run `./color_skript.sh 'hel[a-z]*\>'`?

Comment: It finds strings which start by letters "hel" and the end of string can be whatever. So for example it finds: "hello", "helaa","helab", "helxy"....

Comment: Is that what it's supposed to do, or what it's actually doing? Can you give examples of strings where your script is not working?

Comment: If i want to find "normal" parameter(it means string without: [a-z], [0-9],*,/, > ) such as:"hello", "dog", "aaaa"...etc. so it works. However I have no idea how to work with parameters such as: 'hel[a-z]*\>'. This parameter is a regular expression. Its words like "hello", "helaa"...

Comment: So `./color_skript.sh 'hel[a-z]*\>'` matches nothing? What if you change `grep $word` to `grep "$word"`?

Comment: What if you remove `sed` from your command? Does `grep` match the right words? I think the argument to sed should be `"s/${word}/${color}&{endColor}/g"`. Also, I don't think you need the `-e` after `sed`.

Comment: Ok thank you, i have alredy corrected from $word to "$word". However its same. If I  run ./color_skript.sh 'hel[a-z]*\>' , so my skript looks for string="hel[a-z]*\>" but I need to look for string="helxx". Instead of 'x' can be whatever letters a-z. Maybe I have to parse the parameter for "hel" and next [a-z] but I hoped I gonna find easier solution :)

Comment: Your script seems to work for me, if I replace the second `${word}` after `sed` with `&`, like in my previous comment. Have you figured out whether removing `sed` and just using `grep` matches the right words?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second `${word}` after `sed` should be a `&`. The `&` tells `sed` to echo the pattern it previously matched. So if `$word` is `'hel[a-z]*\>'`, then `&` is "hello" (for example) in the output of `sed`.

Also, I don't think you need the `-e` after `sed`.

```
word=$1
var=$(echo -e $line | grep $word  | sed "s/${word}/${color}&${endColor}/g")
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` itself does all you want:

[image]

You can find more about `GREP_COLORS` in `man grep`.

Comment: It looks like he's using the output in a script, so `grep --color=always` might be better. And that is simpler than using the `sed` command, of course.